# import com.larmor.opencv.MatchTemplate

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, import

I am trying to develop an application which predominantly needs to do the exact thing as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=TrAM8_Fw3yQ) as explained [here](http://www.larmor.com/portal/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=27&Itemid=60).

However i am not able to find the jar file needed to add in the build classpath inside eclipse which lets me import com.larmor.opencv.MatchTemplate.

Please direct me as to where I can find the required resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the jar here(But look like Link is not working) http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmatchtemplate/files/jmatchtemplate/Version%200.5%20beta/JavaOpenCVMatchTemplate_v0.5b_win32.zip/download but this project is look like no updates and may be closed ..

Better you can use https://code.google.com/p/javacv/

Here  are the examples https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv-examples

One post with example https://imiloainf.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/javacv-example/

Comment: The link to the jar file does not open. I'll try the other examples you mentioned. However is there any other link where I can download the required jar? This one doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Oh okay. I'll try the other examples you mentioned then.

Comment: If your question answered you can accept the answer

Comment: I found the jar [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmatchtemplate/files/jmatchtemplate/Version%200.5%20beta/JavaOpenCVMatchTemplate_v0.5b_win32.zip/download). [Pier Paolo](http://www.larmor.com/portal/index.php?option=com_wrapper&Itemid=68) provided the link. However I am getting null pointer exception. I will update my question with the errors that I am getting. @SubodhJoshi It would be great if you could help me sort them out.

Comment: Better ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

The library is downloadable from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmatchtemplate/files/jmatchtemplate/Version%200.5%20beta/JavaOpenCVMatchTemplate_v0.5b_win32.zip/download)